# Changing the data type from varchar to datetime format ,and restoring the previous data

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, timestamp, type-conversion

I have a table with a time_stamp column whose data type is varchar .
It is giving data in the form **"2/28/2013 11:33:45 am"** 
I want to change the data type for this to datetime as i cannot apply any datetime function on varchar.

I already have a lot of data in that table , I want to change its data type and restore all the data .

How can i do this.

Comment: try making a view for that. Regards

Comment: I tried creating a view ,but then all the tiestamp varchar values become null.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert it to datetime using `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(time_stamp, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') = CURDATE()
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/8089)

Comment: So making a view with str_to_date would be something like: create view myView as select *, STR_TO_DATE(time_stamp, '%e/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %r') as new_time_stamp from tablename;

Comment: @mika, yep, and at that point, `new_time_stamp` is already datetime datatype.

Comment: new_time_stamp gets value as null , i need to convert all the varchar values and use them later .

Comment: yaeh it works ..can i change the format as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.and also it only works for the provided timestamp like ('02/28/2013 11:33:45 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') ,i need to change all the rows data .......by any chance i can give column name in place of string in the function